# Alert(document.body.style.width) - не работает

Tags: javascript

Не работает  `alert(document.body.style.width)` - точнее работает, но выводит пустоту, не `NULL` не `undefined` а именно пустое окошко, в чем может быть проблема?
Скриптов нету кроме этой строки. Ошибку заметил когда пытался изменить ширину `body` а она не менялась(

UPD: Заметил вообще такая фигня для всех элементов, не только боди

Также проверка

```
alert(document.body.hasAttribute('style'));
```

дала `false`((

Comment: А DOM у вас на момент выполнения скрипта подгрузился уже?

Comment: @Lucky, да перед /body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запили через `getComputedStyle` и `CurrentStyle` для ie.

И не пугай меня, проверяя свойство с помощью `hasAttribute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/HmmYB/